# Parent process doesn't read from FIFO after child process death

Tags: c, posix, fopen, named-pipes, fifo

So. I have to read and write from a named pipe and I tried to accomplish this by doing the following : Parent process writes a command to a FIFO then waits for the kid to die. The child process reads the command, and  writes something in another fifo. The parent Parent reads the message from the other FIFO and prints the result. I am restricted to using fopen because in my code I use the open from unistd elsewhere, so I don't have the nonblock flag. I ll attach a snippet below. Also, if I use the "w" flag on the child process, the code freezes completely. I get FIFO is a blocking way of communication but I don't get why my parent can't read. Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE* fp2;
    unlink(FIFO_NAME1);
    unlink(FIFO_NAME2);
    //FIFO_NAME[1|2] is a macro containing the FIFO path
    if(mkfifo(FIFO_NAME1, 0666) == -1)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong");
        return -1;
    }
    if(mkfifo(FIFO_NAME2, 0666) == -1)
    {
        printf("Something went wrong");
        return -1;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        char command[MAX_SIZE];
        pid_t pid;
        if((pid=fork()) !=0)
        {
            //parent
                fgets(command, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

                if((fp1= fopen(FIFO_NAME1, "w")) == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error");
                }
                fprintf(fp1, "%s", command);

                fclose(fp1);
                wait(SIGKILL);
                //it never prints this or execute past the wait
                printf("Here \n");

                char response[MAX_SIZE];
                if((fp2= fopen(FIFO_NAME2,"r"))==NULL)
                    perror("");

                fgets(response, MAX_SIZE, fp2);
                fclose(fp2);
                //printf("%s",response);
            }

        
        else
        {
            //child
            char msg[MAX_SIZE];
                   if((fp1 = fopen(FIFO_NAME1, "r")) == NULL)

                {
                    printf("Error");
                }
                fgets(msg, MAX_SIZE, fp1);
                fclose(fp1);

            
                if((fp2= fopen(FIFO_NAME2, "w+")) == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error");
                }

                char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
                strcpy(buffer,"TEST MESSAGE");
       
                fprintf(fp2, "%s", buffer);
                fclose(fp2);

           
            fflush(stdout);
            kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: General hint: `perror` instead of `printf` to actually see what did go wrong with `mkfifo`, `fopen`!

Comment: Try adding `\n` to the *printf("here");` to see if it actually *did* get past. Opening a fifo can block!

Comment: I tried adding the \n but it didn't print anything.

Comment: So please update your code.

Comment: `wait(SIGKILL)` what should that mean? Didn't you get any warning for it? That will either crash or overwrite random memory, especially on x86-64, where the size of an int is different from the size of a pointer.

Comment: include `sys/wait.h` and change it to `wait(0)` (or `int status; ...; wait(&status)`).

Comment: SIGKILL is a macro I was taught about at the uni. I changed to wait(0) (also tried wait NULL ) but this didn't change anything. Should I change the child's kill statement too?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that you cannot half open a FIFO. At least, not unless you open it for reading in non-blocking mode, which you cannot do with `fopen()`. Normally, opening a FIFO for reading will block until the same FIFO is also opened for writing, and *vice versa*.

You are ok in that regard with respect to `FIFO_NAME1`.  The parent opens it for writing and the child opens it for reading.  Once both have done so, they both continue.

But then the parent calls `wait()` (with an incorrect argument, too, but that's a separate issue).  The parent will not return successfully from that `wait` until one of its children terminates.  Only then does it attempt to open `FIFO_NAME2` (for reading), but since the child has already terminated, that FIFO is not open for writing by any process, and the attempt to open it will block indefinitely.

Then there is the child.  It successfully opens the second FIFO only because you specify mode `"w+"`, so that the child alone satisfies both the requirement for a reader and the requirement for a writer.  That is dangerous, however, because if the child does not actually consume any data from the FIFO then it can deadlock by trying to write more data to it than the kernel is willing to buffer at one time.  Moreover, it does not achieve your communication objective, because there is no guarantee that the FIFO will retain the data written by the child when it stops being open for either reading or writing.  Indeed, it probably doesn't.

You need to move or remove the `wait()` call, and if you choose the former then you need to check the docs to discover what kind of argument you should be passing.  If you are willing to trust that the child will not fill the pipe's buffer, then you can move the wait to after the parent opens `FIFO_NAME2` and before it attempts to read anything.  For its part, the child should be certain to open the second FIFO in write-only mode to ensure that parent and child both get that FIFO open before the child starts writing to it.